# Set custom headers to angular-auth-oidc-client token/endsession calls

Tags: angular, identityserver4, angular-auth-oidc-client, identityserver4-extension-grants

I know you can add custom parameters to the authorize call as:

```
const parameters: any = { resource: "ABCD" };
this.oidcSecurity.setCustomRequestParameters(parameters);
```

How to add custom request headers? I am using response_type: 'code'.
Nothing about this mentioned here https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-auth-oidc-client
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Note that this example code above may be outdated now. You set it in the [config](https://nice-hill-002425310.azurestaticapps.net/docs/documentation/custom-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

you can add custom header for this request in the method itself as a parameter https://nice-hill-002425310.azurestaticapps.net/docs/documentation/public-api#authorizeconfigid-string-authoptions-authoptions and you can configure them to be applied every time here https://nice-hill-002425310.azurestaticapps.net/docs/documentation/configuration#customparamsauthrequest